# SQL SELECT: Using the assigned value after 'as' in the next selected parameter before 'as'

Tags: sql, variables, select

I need to use the computed values (after 'as' keyword) of two functions in sql in the next statement. I want to use it because the time of computations decreases x2 in this case.

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT f1() as f_1, f2() as f_2, f_1 - f_2 as f1_minus_f2 FROM mytable
```

where f1(), f2() - some functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can use expression itself (if functions are deterministic):

```
SELECT f1() as f_1, f2() as f_2, f1() - f2() as f1_minus_f2 
FROM mytable
```

2) Use subquery:

```
SELECT sub.f_1, sub.f_2, sub.f_1 - sub.f_2 as f1_minus_f2
FROM (
   SELECT f1() as f_1, f2() as f_2
   FROM mytable
) sub
```

The reason you cannot use it as you want is [`all-at-once`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx) rule:

> "All-at-Once Operations" means that all expressions in the same
>   logical query process phase are evaluated logically at the same time.

Comment: The derived table alternative seems to be safer. Who knows how OP's dbms optimize things (And are the functions deterministic or not?)

Comment: Thank you! The speed of computations really increased x2.